# How can I, as a low bass, sing higher notes in my chest voice? (This is after a couple years of attempting to expand my range)

Tags: voice, vocal-range, voice-training, bass-voice

For the past 2 years or so, I have been using vocal warm ups and exercises to *attempt* to increase my upper range. I can go down to an A1, but I cant comfortably sing higher than an E4. My choir director keeps pushing me to go higher because the high*ish* notes that I can hit have pretty good tone. I don't know whether my range has reached it's peak and I'm destined to sing on the staff, or whether I just need to practice more. Thank you to anyone who has any suggestions.

Comment: See also: [How can I safely extend my vocal range?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/804/70803).

Comment: For a low bass, E4 or F4 is usually the absolute top of the range, similar to B4 or C5 for a tenor.  If you truly have a solid A1 you should probably seek the guidance of a serious voice teacher -- one who counts successful professional singers among his or her students -- to be able to stay up in the stratosphere as choral "bass" parts often demand -- they're frequently written for baritone voices.